# SKSpriteNode is being created with wrong frame

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode, cgpoint

I want to create a square with white eyes

Since the problem is only with the eyes, I will show how I make them

```
let eyeSize = 1.65

let eyeOne = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.whiteColor(), size: CGSize(width: eyeSize, height: eyeSize))
eyeOne.position = CGPointMake(nodeSquare.frame.size.width/2 - (eyeSize/2 + eyeSize), 0)

nodeSquare.addChild(eyeOne);
```

with position (1.64999985694885, 1.64999997615814)

without position (1.64999997615814, 1.64999997615814)

Why is the width different than the height? And change when using position?

Is it because the size is too small?

Comment: Can you see the difference between width/height?

Comment: yes, also one of the eye is smaller in width that the other

Comment: What happens when you set the width/height to 2?

Comment: If it is set to 2, everything is fine